# In tools like tcpdump, when exactly are the network packets captured?

Tags: networking, encryption, tcp, wireshark, tcpdump

One of the tools I am using uses encryption/decryption to send out data over the network. I am modifying the tool and I need to be sure that the data is actually being sent in an encrypted form.

Are **[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)** and **[tcpdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump)** the right tools for the purpose? At which point during the transfer do they capture the network packets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of those tools capture the data exactly as it goes out over the wire. (Think of it as sort of the equivalent of "tee" for output that's going to screen as well as to file; here too, the same data goes to the socket as well as to tcpdump or whatever.)

So yes, if your tool is configured correctly to encrypt the data before sending it, then tcpdump or Wireshark should reflect that in their packet captures.

Comment: While this is a perfectly good answer for the specific question, these tools actually capture the packet as it's delivered to the network adaptor, not as it goes onto the wire.  This means that everything the network adaptor does (which used to be just MAC FCS, but is now usually IP/UDP/TCP checksums as well) does not get captured properly.

Comment: @Will Dean: Do adapters really modify IP and higher level checksums? That's a surprise to me, do you have a reference?

Comment: @GregS - An Intel datasheet for a modern Ethernet controller chip would give you all the gore, but if it's just a matter of not believing me, then http://www.wireshark.org/faq.html#q11.1 should set your mind at ease...

Comment: @GregS - Here you go: http://download.intel.com/design/network/datashts/82541er.pdf - that's a part which can do TCP segmentation too, so the relationship between the bottom of the software stack and the wire will be even more tenuous

Comment: @Will Dean: Thanks for those links. Looks like ethernet adapters are getting to look more like network processors; pretty cool.

Answer (score 20):

Short answer: packets are tapped at very end of software network stack (e.g. in Linux).

Long answer with code digging in tcpdump, libpcap and linux kernel 3.12:

Both Wireshark and tcpdump uses libpcap, for example,

http://sources.debian.net/src/tcpdump/4.5.1-2/tcpdump.c#L1472

```
    if (pcap_setfilter(pd, &fcode) < 0)
```

which in turn install a packet filter via setfilter_op and activate_op. There are lot of implementations of these operations, and I think that on recent Linux `PF_PACKET` will be used with `pcap_activate_linux` [libpcap-1.5.3-2/pcap-linux.c#L1287](http://sources.debian.net/src/libpcap/1.5.3-2/pcap-linux.c#L1287):

```
/*
 * Current Linux kernels use the protocol family PF_PACKET to
 * allow direct access to all packets on the network while
 * older kernels had a special socket type SOCK_PACKET to
 * implement this feature.
 * While this old implementation is kind of obsolete we need
 * to be compatible with older kernels for a while so we are
 * trying both methods with the newer method preferred.
 */
status = activate_new(handle);

    ...
    activate_new(pcap_t *handle)
     ...
    /*
 * Open a socket with protocol family packet. If the
 * "any" device was specified, we open a SOCK_DGRAM
 * socket for the cooked interface, otherwise we first
 * try a SOCK_RAW socket for the raw interface.
 */
sock_fd = is_any_device ?
    socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_ALL)) :
    socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
```

PF_PACKET is implemented in kernel, in the file [net/packet/af_packet.c](http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v3.12/net/packet/af_packet.c#L2478). Initialization of PF_SOCKET is done in `packet_do_bind` with `register_prot_hook(sk)` function (if the device is in UP state), [which calls](http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v3.12/net/packet/af_packet.c#L244) `dev_add_pack` from [net/core/dev.c](http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v3.12/net/core/dev.c#L370) to register the hook:

```
 370 /**
 371 *      dev_add_pack - add packet handler
 372 *      @pt: packet type declaration
 373 *
 374 *      Add a protocol handler to the networking stack. The passed &packet_type
 375 *      is linked into kernel lists and may not be freed until it has been
 376 *      removed from the kernel lists.
 377 *
 378 *      This call does not sleep therefore it can not
 379 *      guarantee all CPU's that are in middle of receiving packets
 380 *      will see the new packet type (until the next received packet).
 381 */
 382
 383 void dev_add_pack(struct packet_type *pt)
 384 {
 385        struct list_head *head = ptype_head(pt);
 386
 387        spin_lock(&ptype_lock);
 388        list_add_rcu(&pt->list, head);
 389        spin_unlock(&ptype_lock);
 390 }
```

I think, pf_packet handler - the [`tpacket_rcv(...)` function](http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v3.12/net/packet/af_packet.c#L1717) - will be registered in ptype_all.

Hooks, registered in `ptype_all` are called for outgoing packets from  `dev_queue_xmit_nit` ("Support routine. Sends outgoing frames to any network taps currently in use.") with `list_for_each_entry_rcu(ptype, &ptype_all, list) { ... deliver_skb ...} .. func`, deliver_skb calls the func which is `tpacket_rcv` for libpcap.

dev_queue_xmit_nit is called from `dev_hard_start_xmit` ([Line 2539 in net/core/dev.c](http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v3.12/net/core/dev.c#L2539)) which is AFAIK the last stage (for outgoing packets) of device-independent packet handling in Linux networking stack.

The same history is for incoming packets, `ptype_all`-registered hooks are called from `__netif_receive_skb_core` with same `list_for_each_entry_rcu(ptype, &ptype_all, list) {.. deliver_skb..}`.  `__netif_receive_skb_core` is called from `__netif_receive_skb` in the very beginning of handling incoming packets

Linux foundation has good description of networking stack (http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/kernel_flow), you can see `dev_hard_start_xmit` on the image http://www.linuxfoundation.org/images/1/1c/Network_data_flow_through_kernel.png (warning, it is huge) at left side just under the legend. And `netif_receive_skb` is inside the rightmost lower square ("net/core/dev.c"), which is fed from IRQ, then NAPI poll or netif_rx and the only exit from here is `netif_receive_skb`.

The picture even shows one of two pf_packet hooks - the leftmost square under legend ("net/packet/af_packet.c") - for outgoing packets.

What is your tool? How it connects to the networking stack? If you can locate the tool in the [Network_data_flow picture](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/images/1/1c/Network_data_flow_through_kernel.png), you will get the answer. For example, Netfilter is hooked (`NF_HOOK`) only in `ip_rcv` (incoming) `ip_output` (local outgoing) and `ip_forward` (outgoing from routing) - just after `netif_receive_skb` and just before `dev_queue_xmit`.

Comment: Some slides about BPF and linux packet sniffing from 2010 [www.cs.columbia.edu/~nahum/w6998/lectures/vpk-columbia-nsdi-lsf.pdf](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~nahum/w6998/lectures/vpk-columbia-nsdi-lsf.pdf)

Comment: `PF_PACKET` is used in all non-ancient versions of libpcap on all 2.x and 3.x Linux kernels.

Comment: The data flow image links are now broken, but there seems to be an archived copy here: http://web.archive.org/web/20170905131225if_/https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/images/1/1c/Network_data_flow_through_kernel.png

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those are the right tools. Wireshark will identify TLS and SSL packets, if that's what you are using for encryption. You can provide Wireshark with the server's private key and decrypt the traffic if necessary (except for ephemeral modes like DHE and ECDHE).